Find v(s) in the circuit below(voltage through the capacitor)

Capacitor initial conditions = 10v, inductor = 2A. Input is the current font.Find voltage through the capacitor
I think i got it but i have no clue whether its right or not, would like to know what i did wrong. My work:
1 - laplace transform
2 - Transform the current font(4/s) in parallel with the 5Ω resitstor to a voltage ( 20/s) one in series with the 5Ω resistor
3 - apply equivalent impedance on the inductor(s), resistor(5Ω) and capacitor(1/4s). added them to Zeq = (4s² + 20s + 1)/4s
4 - add the voltage fonts: -capacitor initial conditions(10/s) + inductor (2) - transformed font(20/s) = 2-30/s = (2s-30)/s = Veq
5 - apply ohm's law in freq to obtain i(s) = Veq(s)/Zeq = 4(2s-30)/(4s²+20s+1)
6 - multiply the inductance of the branch(capacitor) with the current through it, v(s) = 1/4s . 4(2s-30)/(4s²+20s+1) = (2s-30)/s(4s²+20s+1)
7 - also gotta detransform back to time but i can take it from here

Your title says find v(s), which isn't defined on your drawing.  Your text says find the voltage through the capacitor which doesn't make sense. (It should be across the capacitor.)

Have a look at my answer to a similar question. The author made a mistake in their use of Laplace. The answer I gave also deals with initial conditions such as with your question. It may help.

Portuguese 'fonte de corrente' is 'current source' in English. I think the engineering schools of Portugal and Brazil offer online tutorials and guides that cover how you solve transients in circuits using Laplace transform. If you like, you can find multiple online textbooks and course notes in English, and have a double benefit of gaining an EE knowledge and advancing a fluency in technical English.

@JohnD As the other commenter pointed out my technical english is lacking, so i just wrote what i thought it was called in english. The drawing defines v(t) wich is just v(s) after an inverse laplace

@V.V.T a) How did you know my native language was portuguese? lol
b) i  try to stick to the material my professors recommend, which are usually all translated, but that means i have to guess what technical terms are in english before asking for help in forums like these. I'lll take your advice though

@periblepsis i made the same mistake as that author, it did help

@RomuloMendesdeSouza It's a common mistake. Glad the reminder helped out. Thanks for letting me know. :)

Current is though. Voltage is across. Please edit accordingly.

Well, let's analyze this circuit a bit further.  We can use KCL in order to write:
$$\text{I}_\text{source}\left(t\right)=\text{I}_\text{R}\left(t\right)+\text{I}_\text{L & C}\left(t\right)\tag1$$
The current-voltage relations are given by:
$$\text{V}_\text{R}\left(t\right)=\text{I}_\text{R}\left(t\right)\cdot\text{R}\tag2$$
$$\text{V}_\text{R}\left(t\right)-\text{V}\left(t\right)=\text{I}_\text{L & C}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{L}\tag3$$
$$\text{I}_\text{L & C}\left(t\right)=\text{V}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{C}\tag4$$
So, we get:
$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_\text{source}'\left(t\right)&=\text{V}_\text{R}'\left(t\right)\cdot\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{R}}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{R}\left(t\right)-\text{V}\left(t\right)}{\displaystyle\text{L}}\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{source}\left(t\right)&=\text{V}_\text{R}\left(t\right)\cdot\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{R}}+\text{V}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{C}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag5
$$
